# Apache Spark ALS - how is it solving the least square?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

The source code for the Apache Spark ALS can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/ALS.scala).

I am wondering where the Least Squares solving is going on in this source code? I can't find it for the life of me.
When following a tutorial/walkthrough on [Collaborative Filtering](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html), it shows that to perform the ALS function on some ratings you call `ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, lambda)`. Checking the source code and the `train` function calls the `run` function which returns a `MatrixFactorizationModel` with the predicted ratings in it.

Additionally, the API for ALS [(found here)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS) says there is a method called `solveLeastSquares` but it isn't in the source code found in the [first link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/ALS.scala). I would like to learn how the least squares problem is being solved so I can adjust it as necessary.

Comment: I think the implementation is in [`ml/recommendation/ALS.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L309), as opposed to `mllib/recommendation/ALS.scala`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4a17eedb16343413e5b6f8bb58c6da8952ee7ab6/docs/mllib-guide.md):

> (Breaking change) In ALS, the extraneous method solveLeastSquares has been removed. The DeveloperApi method analyzeBlocks was also removed.

However, you can change the branch [to be 1.1 per the docs](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/ALS.scala) you referenced and you will see the `solveLeastSquares` method

Comment: Thank you, Justin. Are you able to offer any advice on how the ALS function work?